# Generate "JSON schema documentation" automatically

Tags: php, documentation, automation

So, I'm using alot of JSON while developing PHP applications. And a function returns json strings or whatever it's really hard to know what they contain, and *it's time consuming to keep documenting up to date especially if it changes alot.*

Would it be a good idea to implement something like this:

Instead of using `return $x` I would implement a function called `_return` which would something like:

```
function _return($obj)
{
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    return $obj;
}
```

It would do more than that, it would look up in the stacktrace what the name of the function is and then I could make this code save the $obj type to an appropriate file, and they could be used to create automatically updated documentation!

Would this be an okay idea? Maybe to time consuming to execute debug_backtrace() at each return?

I would use it like:

```
class T
{
    public function __constructor()
    {
    }

    public function first()
    {
        return $this->second();
    }

    public function second()
    {
        $array = array('david' => 'value', 'test' => 'oj');
        return _return($array);
    }

}

function _return($obj)
{
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
    return $obj;
}

$t = new T();
$t->first();
```

Comment: You don't get it. If it's json string, there's no variabeles representing the keys for example.

Comment: This *does* touch an issue which all documentation solutions fail to cover so far: there is no way to document a data structure that a function returns. The only workaround is to return an object whose members have been defined in a class previously... this doesn't feel like a good approach to the issue, though.

Comment: To me, looks like this question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Pekka웃 I do not see what advantage this "self documenting code" has. It merely logs/dumps some arbitrary data. The same documentation could be added by a copy and paste of some given (and known) data. However, this "manual" approach has the benefit of being cleaned up and consolidated as part of some interface documentation. With the "self documenting approach" above, the code is always right .. even if it is horribly wrong.

Comment: Well, pst, this would remove the procedure of copy-paste + I could detect itself if the return type has changed. It can still be clean without having it written in manuall.

Comment: @DavidEverlöf do you use interactive debuggers? If you're at the point where you're willing to execute the php code to print some info to stdout about return values of a function, you could more easily set a breakpoint in a debugger and inspect the value.

Comment: (I've updated the title; the question is not related to "self documenting code" - hopefully you will be able to find some approaches to help dealing with a constantly changing structure.)

Comment: @pst as said, I'm not saying this is a good approach to the issue. But the fact that there is no way to properly document a complex return value (at least not in any documentation standard I know) is a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several drawbacks.

First, a backtrace can get HUGE - this is the reason there is the function `debug_print_backtrace()`. If you are close to memory limit, pushing the backtrace into a variable that then gets dumped can cancel the script.

Second: A remark: Why don't you `_return` in your "first" method?

Third: If you var_dump stuff, you will destroy any JSON output that might be used and parsed by recent javascript libraries.

Fourth: If you do not know which functions get called when you get a request for a certain URL, then the documentation is not to blame, but your less-than-needed system of non-obvious mapping from URL to executed functions.

Fifth: Debug logging.

Sixth: Output sanitization (it's the counterpart of input validation).

Seventh: There are things like JSON Schema validation. Have a look at http://davidwalsh.name/json-validation for example. This works the other way round by defining the data structure, but if you can compare reality with target result and detect any differences, at least you know where to update something.

Comment: 1. I would not use var_dump() thats just an example. 2. Why I dont use _return first doesnt matter, that was just a test to see how the stackstrace looked.

Comment: Seventh: So this would detect a difference and I would have to update somehting. Wouldnt it be better, as I suggest to then have the code itself update differences and update the documentation automatically?

Comment: Automatically generated documentation probably is the worst of both worlds: It is poorly documenting because machines can only automate the generation process, but do not add any human understanding. And it is documentation and has to be read by the developer to be of any use. A better approach would be to write a great API that verbosely tells the developer if and what is actually wrong with a request, instead of simply refuse to work with an error, and demand the documentation to be read.